# How to change frame size of UIImagePicker when I get photo from photoLibrary or camera?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uipickerview

I want change frame size of UIImagePicker when I get photo from photoLibrary or camera. It only allow square size frame to crop it but I have to give photo in 5:3 ratio in. How can I do it in Swift?

[image: Text]

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerLabel: UIPickerView!

func selectPhoto(){
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    present(picker,animated: true, completion: nil)

    image = imageFromGallery

    imageView.image = imageFromGallery
}



func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    imageFromGallery = (info[.editedImage] as? UIImage)!
    image = imageFromGallery
    imageView.image = imageFromGallery
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I call selectPhoto() to get photos.

There are some questions like my question but I didn't find exact solution for Swift.

Comment: You can set `picker.allowsEditing = false` and then after selecting the image you can try to edit with your custom class or you can use various third-party libraries.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/nkopilovskii/ImageCropper. it is easy to use and you can crop image as per your requirement